# Changing two images in Swift

Tags: image, swift

I have two egg PNG files and what I am trying to make is keep changing

these PNG files stablized position to show like these egg is live.

Sorry that I do not have a code. Please give me some ideas of this problem.

Comment: welcome to this site, but first you need to provide a way forward with something you have attempted. I guarantee it will help you to be better and also it will help us to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add all your images into array and you can animate it this way:

```
var imgListArray :NSMutableArray = []
for countValue in 1...2  {
   imgListArray.addObject(UIImage(named: "c\(countValue).png"))
}

self.imageView.animationImages = imgListArray
self.imageView.animationDuration = 1.0
self.imageView.startAnimating()
```

Hope it will help.